# ¿Cómo puedo hacer esta verificación?

Tags: java, netbeans

primero les explico de manera el proyecto, lo que hace primero es generar aleatoriamente muchos nombres y apellidos, luego de haberlos generado los ordena alfabéticamente los nombres y apellidos, luego lo que quiero hacer es un método para verificar que esté ordenado alfabéticamente, el problema que tengo es que no se que hice mal al hacer la verificación

```
private static boolean Verificar(String[] lista) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.length - 1; i++) {
        if (lista[i].compareTo(lista[i + 1]) > 0) {
            return false;
        }

    }
    return true;
}
```

si el está ordenado el método debería devolver true y si está desordenado debería devolver false pero me siempre me retorna que está desordenado, pienso que es porque son strings compuestos es decir nombre y apellido, como podría hacer la verificación para mi proyecto?
A continuación les dejo mi proyecto.

```
public class QuickSort {

 public static String[] nombres = {"Aaran", "Aaren", "Aarez", "Aarman", "Aaron", "Adrian"};
 public static String[] apellidos = {"Abbott", "Acevedo", "Acosta", "Adams", "Adkins", "Aguilar"};    public static String aux = crearNombres();
public static String aux = crearNombres();
 public static String[] sorted = aux.split(", ");
 static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();


 public static String crearNombres() {

     StringBuilder contenido = new StringBuilder();
     for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
         String aux = nombres[((int) (Math.random() * nombres.length))];
         aux += " " + apellidos[((int) (Math.random() * apellidos.length))];
         if (i < 99999) {
             aux += ", ";
         }
         contenido.append(aux);

     }

     return contenido.toString();
 }

 public static void main(String args[]) {

     QuickSortName algorithm = new QuickSortName();

     algorithm.sort(sorted);


     if(Verificar(sorted) == true){
         System.out.println("ord");
     }


 }

 private static boolean Verificar(String[] lista) {
     for (int i = 0; i < lista.length - 1; i++) {
         if (lista[i].compareTo(lista[i + 1]) > 0) {
             return false;
         }

     }
     return true;
 }
}

class QuickSortName {

 private String input[];
 private int tamaño;

 public void sort(String[] nombres) {

     this.input = nombres;
     tamaño = nombres.length;
     quickSort(0, tamaño - 1);
 }


 private void quickSort(int izq, int der) {
     int i = izq;
     int j = der;


     String pivot = input[izq + (der - izq) / 2];


     while (i <= j) {


         while (input[i].compareToIgnoreCase(pivot) < 0) {
             i++;
         }
         while (input[j].compareToIgnoreCase(pivot) > 0) {
             j--;
         }

         if (i <= j) {
             swap(i, j);

             i++;
             j--;
         }
     }


     if (izq < j) {
         quickSort(izq, j);
     }

     if (i < der) {
         quickSort(i, der);
     }
 }

 private void swap(int i, int j) {
     String temp = input[i];
     input[i] = input[j];
     input[j] = temp;
 }
}
```

Toda ayuda se agradece
Un saludo

Comment: Por favor copia tu codigo, no hagas capturas asi es mas legible! Muchas gracias!

Comment: En tu función `main` tienes esta linea `algorithm.sort(sorted);` ¿qué tiene `sorted`? Lo pregunto porque está definido y rellenado en la definición con `aux.split(", ");` ¿qué es `aux`? ¿Quien llama a `crearNombres()`  y cuándo? En ese código no está.

Comment: Ya está arreglado, me faltaba esa línea de código

Comment: La forma mas facil de verificar que falla, es ver la lista y verificar a ojo si esta ordenada o no.. eso lo hiciste?

Comment: Si ya lo hice y sí está ordenado, no se si tiene que ver que sean Strings[] "compuestos"(es decir que están formados por String [] nombre y String [] apellidos), intenté con un String[] simples y si me verifica que está ordenado pero con mi proyecto no sé como hacerle para que verifique